# TFS from Solution A showing pending changes from Solution B - using team foundation services

Tags: tfs

I'm using Team Foundation Services to manage two different solutions.  They're both in DefaultCollection.  If I open up Solution A in visual studio and make a change, Solution B shows this pending change in Team Explorer.  Is this intended behavior?  Can I change this so that the instance of VS with Solution B doesn't see anything from Solution A?  It's concerning because I'm worried that files from SA are getting added to SB.

Comment: Create separate workspaces for each Project. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16379492/736079

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check-in each project separately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379460/check-in-each-project-separately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of TFS Workspaces.  The files in Solution A are not actually being added to Solution B but in Visual Studio what you are seeing is a list of all the files that are currently checked out in that TFS Workspace on your machine.  This behaviour is by design (and actually can be very helpful if you happen to edit some files outside of Visual Studio).

[Jesse has an excellent write up on how to separate out these things if you want to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379460/check-in-each-project-separately).  Basically you can define a separate TFS workspace for each solution.

`<shameless_plug>`For more information on TFS workspaces you might also want to check out the [Professional Team Foundation Server 2012](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118314093) book.`</shameless_plug>`