# Can I set a .tfignore file per solution if my repository contain many of solutions?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc, tfignore

I have 2 solution in my repository: "A" and "B" under main\A & main\B
the problem that I'm trying to solve is that when I'm changing some file in "A" I can see those file and deliver them when I'm working solution "B".

**Can I set a .tfignore file per solution** and have it ignore all the other files that does not exist out side of the current solution?

If "A" have his own build definition in TFS, **Can I enforce the change-set to include only files from "A" folder?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.tfignore`  could not achieve what your want. You could use below workarounds:

> **Best practice:** A developer can check in pending changes limited to a given *folder/branch/solution* by right-clicking the
>   *folder/solution*, choosing "Check in". For that check-in action, the "Pending Changes" view will **temporarily "exclude" any changes made
>   outside** of that *folder/branch/solution* until you complete the
>   check-in.
>
> **Can it be prevented:**  There is a premade **Check-in Policy** option known as "Enforce check-in to only contain files that are part of
>   current solution". This may work for you, since you are using
>   "Solutions".

[image]

More details info please refer this simialr question: [Why does TFS allow a single changeset to affect multiple branches? If there isn't a very good reason, can this be prevented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178207/why-does-tfs-allow-a-single-changeset-to-affect-multiple-branches-if-there-isn)  and [several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379460/check-in-each-project-separately) per each project.

Comment: Thanks, Does the "Check-in Policy"  is a global setting? Does each developer need to set it manually in his IDE?

Comment: @AviramFireberger It's team project level, to complete this procedure, you must have the Edit project-level information permission set to Allow.  After setting by team project administrator, other developers in the team project will be required to follow the policy. More details please refer: [Add Check-In Policies](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-check-policies)

Comment: Thanks I'll look at the Check-In policy documentation page

Answer (score 0):

What you should actually do in this case is create two workspaces, one for each project. You can then switch between the workspaces as necessary and only see changed files within that workspace.